# Check whether a link to a file is a txt

Tags: c#, file, url, text, directory

I have a varaible UrlList which holds the Directory of which is supposed to be entered in a Text box,
what I want though, is to check whether the given Directory file is a text file or not, so the User gets prompted to either Cancel his Actions or give in a correct file.

Code Snippet:

```
public static string UrlList = @"C:\Users\gbbb\Desktop\Url.txt";
private string[] _UrlRows;
```

and this is the method i sorta started, and then realised i Need help for

```
private void LoadUrls()
{   
    if (UrlList == System.TEXT-FILE)
        _Urlrows = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@UrlList);
}
```

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6613967/2278186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you clearly, you just need to use [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> Returns the extension of the specified path string.

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(@"C:\Users\gbbb\Desktop\Url.txt");

if(ext == ".txt")
{
   string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\gbbb\Desktop\Url.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**`Path.GetExtension`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method

```
if(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path).Equals(".txt",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{

}
```