# Office 2007 PIA - Embed non-text files

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-2007, office-pia

I am working with the Office 2007 PIAs and am trying to generate a large document from x number of user selected documents.  Most of these documents will likely be word docs, but we want to support any file type.

Text documents work fine when inserted using [InsertFile.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertfile%28v=office.14%29.aspx) Pictures can be inserted using [InlineShapes.AddPicture.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture%28v=office.14%29.aspx) How do I embed other document types?  I am looking for the functionality equivalent to drag and dropping any file into Word.  If I try to use the InsertFile method, it just writes out the binary content of non text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed non-text files in Word via Interop, you use [InlineShapes.AddOLEObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addoleobject%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> I am looking for the functionality equivalent to drag and dropping any file into Word.

This does the trick for me:

```
public void InsertFile(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection CurrentSelection, string FileName)
{
object FileName = fileName;
object missing = Type.Missing;
CurrentSelection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ref missing, ref FileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  I'm playing with some binary file autodetection to decide whether to attach the files or just InsertText per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910873/how-can-i-determine-if-a-file-is-binary-or-text-in-c