PowerShell, distinguish between files that are text or binary in nature
I have a script that will look through all files in some folders and then search for text inside them. The problem is that I want it to selectively only search through files that are not binary in nature. This seems quite difficult to do. I've tried to combine many techniques, but it still fails to work properly (in that many files, e.g., C:\csb.log which appears to be a system file of some kind, are flagged as binary, but they are not, and are just text files, and then there are files like PDF or EPUB / MOBI which are sort of text, but sort of not; it's quite confusing). I particularly don't like having to have lines like the below
$binaryExtensions = @('.exe', '.dll', '.bin', '.iso', '.zip', '.tar', '.rar', '.7z', '.gz', '.pdf', '.epub', '.mobi', '.azw', '.azw2', '.azw3')

as I'd like to think we can quickly detect the nature of a file without relying upon it's file extension.
How can we detect (hopefully simply) files that are not binary and so can be cleanly searched through for text, and possibly also files that are partly binary and partly text, like PDF, EPUB, MOBI, and ignore the binary parts but cleanly search for the text in the not binary parts)?
Here is my PowerShell attempt so far.
function Is-BinaryFile {
    param (
        [string]$FilePath,
        [switch]$errors
    )
    
    # Define the log file path based on the function name
    $functionName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    $logFile = "$Env:TEMP\$functionName.log"

    # If $errors is specified without $FilePath, output the log file contents
    if ($errors -and -not $FilePath) {
        if (Test-Path $logFile) {
            Get-Content -Path $logFile
        } else {
            Write-Host "Log file not found: $logFile"
        }
        return
    }

    # If the FilePath is a directory, consider it to be a 'binary file' for this and return true
    if ((Test-Path $FilePath) -and (Get-Item $FilePath).PSIsContainer) {
        return $true
    }

    # Check for common binary file extensions before reading the file
    $binaryExtensions = @('.exe', '.dll', '.bin', '.iso', '.zip', '.tar', '.rar', '.7z', '.gz', '.pdf', '.epub', '.mobi', '.azw', '.azw2', '.azw3')

    $fileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($FilePath).ToLower()

    if ($binaryExtensions -contains $fileExtension) {
        return $true
    }

    # Retry opening the file if it's locked using FileStream in shared mode
    $maxRetries = 5
    $retryDelay = 2  # in seconds
    $attempt = 0
    $fileStream = $null

    while ($attempt -lt $maxRetries -and -not $fileStream) {
        try {
            # Open file with shared read/write mode
            $fileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($FilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
        } catch {
            Write-Host "File is locked, retrying in $retryDelay seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryDelay
            $attempt++
        }
    }

    if (-not $fileStream) {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"
        $logMessage = "[$timestamp] Failed to open '$FilePath' after $maxRetries attempts"
        Write-Host $logMessage
        $logMessage | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
        return $false
    }

    # Rest of your code to check if it's a binary file...
    $reader = $null
    try {
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader($fileStream)
        
        # Check for BOM (Byte Order Mark)
        $bomBuffer = New-Object byte[] 4
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($bomBuffer, 0, $bomBuffer.Length)

        if ($bytesRead -ge 2 -and (
            ($bomBuffer[0] -eq 0xEF -and $bomBuffer[1] -eq 0xBB -and $bomBuffer[2] -eq 0xBF) -or # UTF-8 BOM
            ($bomBuffer[0] -eq 0xFF -and $bomBuffer[1] -eq 0xFE) -or # UTF-16 LE BOM
            ($bomBuffer[0] -eq 0xFE -and $bomBuffer[1] -eq 0xFF) # UTF-16 BE BOM
        )) {
            return $false  # It's a text file
        }

        # If no BOM, continue checking for non-printable characters
        $binaryBytes = 0
        $textBytes = 0
        $buffer = New-Object byte[] 1024
        while (($bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $bytesRead; $i++) {
                if ($buffer[$i] -eq 0) {
                    $binaryBytes++
                } elseif ($buffer[$i] -lt 32 -and $buffer[$i] -ne 9 -and $buffer[$i] -ne 10 -and $buffer[$i] -ne 13) {
                    $binaryBytes++
                } else {
                    $textBytes++
                }
            }
        }
        return $binaryBytes -gt $textBytes
    } finally {
        if ($reader) { $reader.Close() }
        if ($fileStream) { $fileStream.Close() }
    }
}


You are aware there is no absolute way to determine what you're asking for right? It might work in most cases but it can also be wrong in some.

Ok, that's a shame, I'm not aware of that (there are many things I'm not sure on! ). It would be good to get to the best case situation that is fast and efficient. Are there any additional techniques that you can think of that would improve this detection?

Many answers suggest using [char]::IsControl reading the first X bytes from the files to determine if the file is binary or not, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910873/how-can-i-determine-if-a-file-is-binary-or-text-in-c - to base the condition on the file's extension isnt a good approach imo.

What seems to be a reasonable approach is the one from this answer, essentially, open the file with a StreamReader (it tries to detect the right encoding) and read char by char to determine if the character is a control character, in this case it's using:

Greater than NULL (0) and lower than Back Space (8) OR
Greater than Carriage Return (13) and lower than Substitute (26)

If that condition is met then the file is binary otherwise it's a text file, of course this isn't absolute but should work for most cases.
Something to note, OP in his answer decided to read bytes until EOF and this can be slow. I decided to simply translate the c# code to powershell, you can however add a condition in the while loop to limit to how many characters you want to read before deciding if it's or not a binary.
function Test-Binary {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Path')]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPath',
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
            Mandatory)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]] $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'Path',
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipeline,
            Position = 0)]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string[]] $Path
    )

    begin {
        # Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652983/15339544
        class Utils {
            hidden static [char] $NUL = [char] 0  # Null char
            hidden static [char] $BS = [char] 8   # Back Space
            hidden static [char] $CR = [char] 13  # Carriage Return
            hidden static [char] $SUB = [char] 26 # Substitute

            hidden static [bool] IsControlChar([int] $ch) {
                return ($ch -gt [Utils]::NULL -and $ch -lt [Utils]::BS) -or
                       ($ch -gt [Utils]::CR -and $ch -lt [Utils]::SUB)
            }

            static [bool] IsBinary([System.IO.FileInfo] $fileinfo) {
                if ($fileinfo.Length -eq 0) {
                    return $false
                }

                $reader = $null
                try {
                    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($fileinfo.FullName)
                    while (($char = $reader.Read()) -ne -1) {
                        if ([Utils]::IsControlChar($char)) {
                            return $true
                        }
                    }
                    return $false
                }
                finally {
                    if ($reader) {
                        $reader.Dispose()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($item in Get-Item @PSBoundParameters) {
            if ($item -isnot [System.IO.FileInfo]) {
                Write-Error "Item is a directory: '$($item.FullName)'..."
                continue
            }

            try {
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    Path     = $item.FullName
                    IsBinary = [Utils]::IsBinary($item)
                }
            }
            catch {
                $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
            }
        }
    }
}


The usage is simply:
PS> Test-Binary myFile.ext
PS> Get-ChildItem -File | Test-Binary
PS> Test-Binary *.ext


@KJ that file is seen as text using this approach, not sure if that's expected or not

For sure, 100% of files are binary, but the object is more "should I spend CPU cycles parsing this file for the text that I am looking for, or, is it not really text in nature, and thus I should skip it and only try to read files that have high confidence of being text in nature". That's quite useful for me when trying to parse/find files containing certain text among 100's of thousands of files on a system, i.e. quickly reject obviously binary files, only search within high-confidence text-in-nature files.

Example of a file that is all text, but has something that makes the above function decide that it's binary; but a select-string etc will see it as text.
PS C:> Format-Hex .\csb.log
Label: C:\csb.log
      Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
             00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
      ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----

0000000000000000 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74 65 78 74 20 66 This is a text f
0000000000000010 69 6C 65 21 00 0D 0A                            ile! ��

Absolutely, it's the 3 non-printable characters (which I think represent utf-8 or something). A really great tweak would be to eliminate all encoding types from the detection - I tried to do this in my original, but I'm not sure how successful that was. I have to keep testing with the excellent answers from Santiago and mklement0.

Another option using the same logic as in my previous answer but in this case it extends the FileInfo type adding an IsBinary property. This is something you could add to your $PROFILE:
class Utils {
    hidden static [bool] IsControlChar([int] $ch) {
        return ($ch -gt 0 -and $ch -lt 8) -or
               ($ch -gt 13 -and $ch -lt 26)
    }

    static [bool] IsBinary([psobject] $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo.Length -eq 0) {
            return $false
        }

        $reader = $null
        try {
            $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($fileinfo.FullName)
            while (($char = $reader.Read()) -ne -1) {
                if ([Utils]::IsControlChar($char)) {
                    return $true
                }
            }
            return $false
        }
        finally {
            if ($reader) {
                $reader.Dispose()
            }
        }
    }
}

$updateTypeDataSplat = @{
    MemberType = 'CodeProperty'
    MemberName = 'IsBinary'
    TypeName   = 'System.IO.FileInfo'
    Value      = [Utils].GetMethod('IsBinary')
}
Update-TypeData @updateTypeDataSplat

Then every cmdlet that returns FileInfo instances will have this property attached, for example with Get-ChildItem:
Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object FullName, IsBinary


Santiago Squarzon's helpful answers provide dependency-free, cross-platform solutions - though note that reading files character by character in PowerShell code is slow, and, as recommended, implementing a limit on how many bytes are read is advisable.

Let me add an alternative that relies on the (POSIX-mandated) Unix file utility, albeit an enhanced implementation that must support the following non-POSIX options:
--mime-encoding, -b, and -f -; fortunately, this is true for "Every known Linux distribution" and "Most known BSD distributions (FreeBSD, NetBSD, Darwin/Mac OS X, etc)", per this page maintained by the enhanced implementation's original author; a current man page can be found here.
On Windows, the custom Get-FileEncoding function below also works, but if and only if:

If WSL is enabled.

Also, a fundamental limitation is that it only works for local file-system paths: neither paths based on mapped drives nor UNC paths are supported.[1]


file recognizes a wide variety of file type based on their content[2] (rather than by their filename extension), and, as a C-based implementation, is fast.
Get-FileEncoding uses file's --mime-encoding option to report a given file's character encoding, using the MIME names of encodings, as you would find in the Content-Type header of HTTP requests; e.g., us-ascii, utf-8, iso-8859-1, or utf-16le.
Given that the concept of a character encoding only applies to text-based files, binary is reported for all non-text files, which can be taken advantage of as follows:
# Outputs [pscustomobject] instances, each with a .Path (full file-system path)
# and a Boolean .IsBinary property
Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Get-FileEncoding | 
  Select-Object Path, @{ Name='IsBinary'; Expression={ $_.Encoding -eq 'binary' } }

As the name suggests, however, Get-FileEncoding's primary purpose is to report the encoding of text files; e.g., the following reports the character encoding of all *.ps1 files in the current directory:
Get-FileEncoding *.ps1


Get-FileEncoding source code:
function Get-FileEncoding {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Reports the given files's character encoding in MIME format.
  
  .DESCRIPTION
  IMPORTANT: 
    * On Unix-like platforms, /usr/bin/file is used behind the scenes.
    * On Windows, this utility only works if WSL is enabled and if the default
      distro comes with /usr/bin/file
        * CAVEAT: On Windows, only LOCAL files are supported as input; 
                 NO support for mapped drives / UNC paths.
    * In both cases, /usr/bin/file must support the following (non-POSIX) options:
      --mime-encoding -b -f -
      However, per https://www.darwinsys.com/file/, this is true for
      all Linux distros and most BSD distros, including macOS.

  Outputs [pscustomobject] instances with 'Path' and 'Encoding' properties.

  The 'Encoding' values are strings:
  
   * They are the encoding names as used in the 'charset' attribute of 
    Content-Type HTTP headers, e.g. 'us-ascii', 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', or 'utf-16le'
   * Non-text files as well as empty files report 'binary'.
   * Symlinks are invariably followed.
     If a symlink is broken or a file's content cannot be read,
     'ERROR: ...' is reported.
  
  .EXAMPLE
  Get-ChildItem -File | Get-FileEncoding
  
  Reports the character encoding of all files in the current directory.
  
  .EXAMPLE
  Get-FileEncoding *.txt
  
  Reports the character encoding of all files in the current directory.
  #>
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Wildcard')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0, ParameterSetName = 'Wildcard')]
    [string[]] $Path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName = 'Literal')] 
    [Alias('PSPath', 'lp')]
    [string[]] $LiteralPath
  )
  # NOTE: The following runs in an implicit end {} block, i.e. all input paths are collected first.
  $isWin = $env:OS -eq 'Windows_NT'
  # On Windows, make sure that WSL is enabled, with an available `file` utility.
  if ($isWin -and -not $(try { wsl.exe -e file --version } catch {})) { throw 'This utility requires WSL to be enabled and the default WSL distribution to have a `file` utility.' }
  # Resolve all input paths, to full, file-system-native paths.
  [string[]] $paths = 
    if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { Convert-Path -LiteralPath @($input) }
    else { if ($LiteralPath) { Convert-Path -LiteralPath $LiteralPath } else { Convert-Path -Path $Path } }
  if (-not $paths) { return }
  $i = 0
  $sb = 
    if ($isWin) { # Call via WSL.
      # Makes sure that WinPS too sends UTF-8 via the pipeline, which is what `wsl.exe` expects.
      # NOTE: We needn't worry about [Console]::OutputEncoding, because we only expect all-ASCII output.
      $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
      # Custom, local-paths-only translation of Windows paths to WSL paths.
      { $paths | ForEach-Object { $_.ToLower() -replace '^([a-z]):', '/mnt/$1' -replace '\\', '/' } | wsl.exe tr -d "`r" `| file --mime-encoding -b -f - }
    }
    else { # Unix-like environment; call `file` directly.
      { $paths | file --mime-encoding -b -f - }
    }
  & $sb | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path     = $paths[$i++]
      Encoding = $_
    }
  }
}


[1] While the WSL-side wslpath utility, which translates between Windows and WSL-format paths, does support UNC paths in principle, it only recognizes them if a matching WSL-side mount has previously been established for a given file share (it too doesn't recognize mapped drives, though that problem could be solved on the Windows side by resolving paths based on mapped drives to their underlying UNC paths). wslpath regrettably supports only one path argument at a time, making it unsuitable for transforming large numbers of Windows paths for performance reasons.
[2] How many bytes - at most - are read from a given file is configurable via the -P option (see the man page); Get-FileEncoding does not expose this option, however.
