# What advantage is there to using UTF-8 over UTF-16?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF8, UTF16, and UTF32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496321/utf8-utf16-and-utf32)

I am always reading things saying to write my source code in UTF-8 and stay way from other encodings, but it also seems like UTF-16 is an improved version of UTF-8. What is the difference between them, and is there any advantage to either one?

Comment: UTF-16 has ***all the disadvantages*** of both UTF-8 and of UTF-32 alike, while simultaneously enjoying ***none of the advantages of either.*** It’s the worst of both worlds, and the best of none. Use UTF-8 for storage and transfer; use UTF-32 for memory operations; and use UTF-16 for nothing.

Comment: "use UTF-16 for nothing" ... except when interacting with APIs that require it, such as the Win32 API.

Answer (score 5):

This should help :)

http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-16/

> Summary:
>
> 1. UTF-8 and UTF-16 are both used for encoding characters
> 2. UTF-8 uses a byte at the minimum in encoding the characters while UTF-16 uses two
> 3. A UTF-8 encoded file tends to be smaller than a UTF-16 encoded file
> 4. UTF-8 is compatible with ASCII while UTF-16 is incompatible with ASCII
> 5. UTF-8 is byte oriented while UTF-16 is not
> 6. UTF-8 is better in recovering from errors compared to UTF-16

Comment: 7. With relaxed validation, all possible invalid UTF-16 can be round-tripped through UTF-8. The reverse does not hold.