# utf8_unicode_ci utf16_unicode_ci utf32_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding

What are differences among utf8_unicode_ci,  utf16_unicode_ci and utf32_unicode_ci in MySql?

Are there any performance differences?

Comment: This is better suited for [dba.se], I think.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496321/utf8-utf16-and-utf32) Are you looking for this ? @faridmovsumov

Comment: @theunlucky In the context of MySQL? dba is probably the better place for it though.

Comment: @theunlucky I don't know if these issues are the same I want to know about MySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utf8_unicode_ci utf16_unicode_ci utf32_unicode_ci are collation type. You can choose according to your need and what is your charset type. For instance if you are using utf8, then you need to use utf8_unicode_ci(or any other in utf8_ collation family), for utf16 you should use utf16_unicode_ci and so on.

For different charset type reference from [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496321/utf8-utf16-and-utf32)

> UTF-8 has an advantage where ASCII are most prevalent characters. In
> that case most characters only occupy one byte each. It is also
> advantageous that UTF-8 file containing only ASCII characters has the
> same encoding as an ASCII file.
>
> UTF-16 is better where ASCII is not predominant, it uses 2 bytes per
> character primarily. UTF-8 will start to use 3 or more bytes for the
> higher order characters where UTF-16 remains at just 2 most of the
> time.
>
> UTF-32 will cover all possible characters in 4 bytes each which makes
> it pretty bloated, I can't think of any advantage to use it.

Hope it helps...