# difference between L"" and u8""

Tags: c++, string, c++11, utf-8

Is there any difference between the followings?

```
auto s1 = L"你好";
auto s2 = u8"你好";
```

Are `s1` and `s2` referring to the same type?
If no, what's the difference and which one is preferred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same type.

`s2` is a UTF-8 or narrow string literal. The [C++11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section 2.14.5 *String literals* paragraph 7 says:

> A string literal that begins with **`u8`, such as `u8"asdf"`**, is a **UTF-8 string literal** and is initialized with the given characters as encoded in UTF-8.

And paragraph 8 says:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type **“array of *n* `const char`”**, where *n* is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

`s1` is a wide string literal which can support UTF-16 and UTF-32. Section 2.14.5 *String literals* paragraph 11 says:

> A string literal that begins with **`L`, such as `L"asdf"`**, is a *wide string literal*. A wide string literal has type **“array of *n* `const wchar_t`”**, where *n* is the size of the string as defined below; it has static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.

See [UTF8, UTF16, and UTF32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496321/utf8-utf16-and-utf32) for a good discussion on the differences and advantages of each.

A quick way to determine types is to use [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```
std::cout << typeid(s1).name() << std::endl ;
std::cout << typeid(s2).name() << std::endl ;
```

On my system this is the output:

```
PKw
PKc
```

Checking each of these with `c++filt -t`  gives me:

```
wchar_t const*
char const*
```

Comment: @r-martinho-fernandes My original markup was pretty bad and I appreciate the edit it looks much better. I was way too tired when I posted, but the comment with the edit was uncalled for and if it was anyone else I would have flagged it.

Answer (score 4):

`L""` creates a null-terminated string, of type `const wchar_t[]`. This is valid in C++03. (Note that `wchar_t` refers to an implementation-dependent "wide-character" type).

`u8""` creates a null-terminated UTF-8 string, of type `const char[]`. This is valid only in C++11.

Which one you choose is strongly dependent on what needs you have. `L""` works in C++03, so if you need to work with older code (which may need to be compiled with a C++03 compiler), you'll need to use that. `u8""` is easier to work with in many circumstances, particularly when the system in question normally expects `char *` strings.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a wide character string, which might be encoded as UTF-16 or UTF-32, or something else entirely (though Unicode is now common enough that a completely different encoding is pretty unlikely).

The second is a string of narrow characters using UTF-8 encoding.

As to which is preferred: it'll depend on what you're doing, what platform you're coding for, etc. If you're mostly dealing with something like a web page/URL that's already encoded as UTF-8, and you'll probably just read it in, possibly verify its content, and later echo it back, it may well make sense to store it as UTF-8 as well.

Wide character strings vary by platform. If, for one example, you're coding for Windows, and a lot of the code interacts directly with the OS (which uses UTF-16) then storing your strings as UTF-16 can make a great deal of sense (and that's what Microsoft's compiler uses for wide character strings).