# My SQL to get String from Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct a string within an sql query from a date range to create another column to denote the Monday of the week the day belongs in, i.e. create the below:

```
salesDate   mondayText
13/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
14/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
15/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
16/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
17/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
18/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
19/11/17    Mon 13 Nov
20/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
21/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
22/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
23/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
24/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
25/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
26/11/17    Mon 20 Nov
```

I've tried the following but it seems a bit like overkill:

```
CONCAT(LEFT(DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(`order_date`),LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(`order_date`),2,'0'),' ','Monday'), '%X%V %W')),3),' ',
            EXTRACT(DAY FROM (`order_date` - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(`order_date`) Day)),' ',
    LEFT(MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(`order_date`),LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(`order_date`),2,'0'),' ','Monday'), '%X%V %W')),3)) AS mondayText
```

An this causes problems when weeks span months. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql STR\_TO\_DATE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561169/mysql-str-to-date-not-working)

Comment: Quite the opposite, I'm trying to get the mondayText data from the date, not the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `salesDate` column is string and has the following format - *dd/MM/YY*. You can simply make use of [MySQL datetime functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html),

- DATE_FORMAT
- STR_TO_DATE
- SUBDATE
- WEEKDAY

Example

```
DATE_FORMAT(SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(salesDate,'%d/%m/%y'), WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(salesDate,'%d/%m/%y'))), '%a %d %b')
```

Here's a [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3b02/1).

However, you don't have to use `STR_TO_DATE` if the column's datatype is already *DATETIME*.

[Demo 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600c78/1).

Comment: Awesome, thanks, completely understand it now, was going about this completely the wrong way!