# Get Unicode Encoded Characters (Kannada Lanuguage) from given String

Tags: java, spring-mvc, unicode, unicode-string

```
String s1="\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F";   // Hello
String s2="\u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F";  // ಮುಖಪುಟ (Kannada Language)

System.out.println("s1: " + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s1));  // s1: Hello
System.out.println("s2: " + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(s2));  // s2: ??????
```

When I print `s1`, I get the result as `Hello`.
When I print `s2`, I get the result as `???????`.

I want the output as `ಮುಖಪುಟ` for `s2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where do you want to get the output: on the command prompt of Windows/Linux or the console view of an IDE?  Please mention.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha IDE Console..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Comment: @Raedwald No. my question is not related to your suggested question

Comment: 2 of the 3 answers suggest properly setting the character encoding. The text of your question does not indicate any awareness of the importance of character encoding for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(os);
 ps.println("\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F \u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F");  
 String output = os.toString("UTF8");
 System.out.println("result: "+output);   //  Hello ಮುಖಪುಟ
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the encoding like "UTF-8"
try this

```
String s1="\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F";   // Hello
String s2="\u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F";  // ಮುಖಪುಟ (Kannada Language)

System.out.println("s1: " + new String(s1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
System.out.println("s2: " + new String(s2.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: @SantoshJadi can you show me the exact code and output.

Comment: still i didn't started the implementation, its just for a practice purpose. i just want to know, why that's not working for other languages.

Comment: This won't work because `new String(s2.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")` is actually a NOP.

Comment: @Igoranze but then I would expect `System.out.println("s2: " + s2);` to work just as well...

Comment: @piet.t The difference is the Unicode "UTF-8", While a normal String uses "UTF-16", the new String is expected to use "UTF-8". See this link for more info about the differences. http://stackoverflow.com/a/496361/4985572

Comment: @Ignoranze `java.lang.String` always uses UTF-16, no way around that. Only when converting to or from `byte`s e.g. when writing to or reading from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Eclipse` then please have a look at: https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Please simply output on the console as follows:-

```
String s1="\u0048\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F";   
String s2="\u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F";
System.out.println("s1: " + s1);  // s1
System.out.println("s2: " + s2);  // s2
```

Hope, this is helpful to you.

Comment: yes i tried this, only working for s1 (English Language), its not working for s2 (Kannada language), giving same output as ???????.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably that `System.out` is not prepared to deal with Unicode. It is an output stream that gets encoded in the so called *default encoding*.

The *default encoding* is most often (i.e. on Windows) some proprietary 8-bit character set, that simply can't handle unicode.

My tip: For the sake of testing, create your own PrintStream or PrintWriter with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: yes i check with PrintStream and its printing correctly.   PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"); printStream.println("\u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F");  how can i assign printed value to a String?

Comment: @Chetan How about `String foo = "\u0CAE\u0CC1\u0C96\u0CAA\u0CC1\u0C9F";`

Comment: its working with PrintStream in a console but when i send it to browser, it prints like ???????.

Comment: Please ask a new question if your original problem is solved. No follow-up question in comments. And make sure to explain what "send it to browser" actually means.

Comment: i will add you +1, once i reach 15 reputations ;)