# Can we use "UTF-16" in meta tag in HTML?

Tags: html

Will it behave differently from the use of **UTF-8** in *Meta* tag in HTML code?

Comment: If you serve the page with `content-type: text/html; charset=utf-16`, I guess it should work. But, as a rule, don't use UTF-16, or any other charset (it is a mess and confusing enough already), just always and only use UTF-8 if you have the choice.

Comment: @BartFriederichs thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496321/utf-8-utf-16-and-utf-32)

Comment: It's not about the difference between UTF types,  it's about why we use UTF-8 as standard in HTML.

Answer (score 6):

UTF-16 is incompatible with ASCII.

Consequently, **w3.org** says:

> **Working with UTF-16**
>
> According to the results of a Google sample of several billion pages,
>   less than 0.01% of pages on the Web are encoded in UTF-16. UTF-8
>   accounted for over 80% of all Web pages, if you include its subset,
>   ASCII, and over 60% if you don't. **You are strongly discouraged from
>   using UTF-16 as your page encoding.**
>
> If, for some reason, you have no choice, here are some rules for
>   declaring the encoding. They are different from those for other
>   encodings.
>
> **The HTML5 specification forbids the use of the meta element to declare
>   UTF-16, because the values must be ASCII-compatible.** Instead you
>   should ensure that you always have a byte-order mark at the very start
>   of a UTF-16 encoded file. In effect, this is the in-document
>   declaration.
>
> Furthermore, if your page is encoded as UTF-16, do not declare your
>   file to be "UTF-16BE" or "UTF-16LE", use "UTF-16" only. The byte-order
>   mark at the beginning of your file will indicate whether the encoding
>   scheme is little-endian or big-endian. (This is because content
>   explicitly encoded as, say, UTF-16BE should not use a byte-order mark;
>   but HTML5 requires a byte-order mark for UTF-16 encoded pages.)

(My bold).

**Source:** https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations